# MySQL and German characters

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, character

We have a website that we have converted into German - the back end is a MySQL DB (version 5.5) and the site is written in PHP 5.6 and HTML. 
The issue we have is with special characters when we retrieve data from the tables and display it on the page. For example:

It is something our side, to do with the SQL retrieve from the database. In the table we correctly store the special characters:

Stored in the address table field: Nurnberg (with umlaut)

But when displayed on the web page: N�rnberg

Encoding on the page is charset="ISO-8859-1" and SQL connection is 
•   MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8) 
•   MySQL connection collation: UTF8-unicode-ci

All other special characters display fine from static text, just not when retrieved from the DB.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: HTML does not support Umlaute. Use `&uuml;` for `ü`. But there is certainly a function for that in PHP I guess.

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: @juergend Was?! HTML supports *all possible characters a computer can express* just fine.

Comment: Resolved - thank you!